# IPrevent direct file access from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Whenever I am trying to direct access my file that time it's allow me to download that file, but I do not want that. For that I already did many things but still seems like its not working for me.
Maybe still I am missing something.

```
Actual File location :
     /var/www/html/project1/Recording/2016-11-03_11:01:23_6105_4270.wav
URL :
     localhost/project1/Recording/2016-11-03_11:01:23_6105_4270.wav
```

If I execute above URL then its directly allow me to download that file. But that's not good for me.

I have made below things

```
   File :  /var/www/html/project1/Recording/.htaccess
.htaccess code : 
          <FilesMatch "\.(wav)$">
              Order Allow,Deny
               Deny from all
          </FilesMatch> 
   File : /var/www/html/project1/Recording/index.php
  index.php code :
            <?php
             header("location:http://localhost/project1/");
            ?>
```

Is there anything need to add/missing to prevent download file?

Comment: Since you are using `.htaccess` files, I assume you are using Apache. What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: why dont you store these files some where else, i mean other than the webroot. You can store them in "/var/www/recordings". PHP with right permission can read or write a file from/to anywhere

Comment: im not an expert in `.htaccess` but i recon your "direct file access prevention" code would be something like this `<Directory  ~ "\app">Order allow,denyDeny from all</Directory>`

here is the link for further information http://webrewrite.com/deny-access-of-files-and-folders-through-htaccess/

Comment: @Doom5
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26

Comment: @PushpendraSinghThakur Yeah i know that we can store at any other places but thats not possible for me

Comment: @ImmortalDude Thanks for reply but i have already did that things in .htacces but still its not work for me

Comment: @AnkitDoshi please include your current `.htaccess` code please

Comment: @ImmortalDude I have added my latest .htaccess code as well as i am also not a master in .htaccess that's why i post my question here
I also tried your code but that's also not working

Comment: ok so whats php code doing in htaccess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129095/discussion-between-ankit-doshi-and-immortal-dude).